# Django PolygonField: how to display on map?

Tags: web-mapping, polygon, geodjango

Extremely beginner question.

I have a GeoDjango model with a MultiPolygonField. How do I retrieve the value of this field and display it as a polygon on a map?

```
class county(models.Model):
    cd = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=27700)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

def lsoa(request, code):
    county = get_object_or_404(county.objects, cd=code)
    return render_to_response('county.html', { 'county': county }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I know GeoJson is involved somewhere along the line, but I'm struggling with to get it out of Django, and with how to display it.

Answer (score 7):

There's a few ways to do this.  One is to simply put the geojson of the object into a javascript variable and then render the geometry of the geojson into your map.  For example, in your header of county.html you can put something like:

```
var countyJson = {{county.geom.geojson|safe}};
```

You may also wish to transform the geometry into epsg:4326 before bringing it into the template so you get the standard lat/lng commonly used in most many frameworks.  You can do this in your view:

```
county.geom.transform(4326)
```

If you are still stuck, info on what clientside mapping framework (eg Google Maps, OpenLayers, etc.) you are using since the syntax for displaying the polygon will vary.

Answer (score 1):

So depending on the size of your geometries, you may not want to fetch the entire polygon as part of the initial request. (Load times would get awful)

So create a view you can hit with ajax:

```
def get_location_polygons(request):
    response_data = {'data':None,}
    location = get_object_or_404(County, cd=request.GET['code'])

    # Build the polygons        
    response_data['data'] = {
        'polygons' : location.geom.geojson,
        'title' : location.cd
    }

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype="application/json")
```

Then Call some JS to parse/display the polygon:

```
function fetch_polygons(code)
{       
    $.ajax({
        url : '/get-location-polygons/', // Whatever URL You decide for that AJAX request
        data : {'code': code},
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'GET',
        success: function(data)
        {
                poly = JSON.parse(data.data['polygons'])
                var paths = coord_to_paths(poly.coordinates);
                polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
                    paths : paths, 
                    strokeColor : "#CCC", 
                    strokeOpacity : .5, 
                    strokeWeight : 1, 
                    fillColor : "#CCC", 
                    fillOpacity : .5
                });

                polygon.setVisible(true)
                polygon.setMap(map); // Your map reference
                polygon.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<strong>' + data.data.title + '</strong>',
                }); 
        }
    });     
}

function coord_to_paths(coords)
{
    var paths = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++)
    { 
        for (var j = 0; j < coords[i].length; j++)
        { 
            var path = []; 
            for (var k = 0; k < coords[i][j].length; k++)
            {
                path.push(ll); 
            } 
            paths.push(path); 
        } 
    }

    return paths;       
}
```

coord_to_paths is pretty important for making multipolygon abjects behave nicely in V2 of the gmaps api.

Comment: This is a pared down example of what I'm doing here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27300/geodjango-slowness-and-debugging