# Add a GeoDjango PolygonField to a Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, polygon, geodjango

Is it possible to add a `GeoDjango` `PolygonField` to a Leaflet map?
I've tried to do that by adding the js code below to my template, but I get a `TypeError: t is null` instead:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function map_init(map, options) {
        // zoom to point
        map.setView([51.9923, -2.1580], 12);

        // get polygon
        var polygon = "{{ obj.geometry.geojson }}";
        var polygon = L.polygon(polygon).addTo(map);
    }
</script>
```

In the code above, `obj` is my Django object and the PolygonField is called `geometry`. So I thought maybe I should use the `coords` property instead. But the same error persisted.

I can add a polygon normally if it's hardcoded like in the [official tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/):

```js
var polygon = L.polygon([
    [51.509, -0.08],
    [51.503, -0.06],
    [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(mymap);)
```

**Edit:**

Strangely enough, if I turn the tuple string of `{{ obj.geometry.coords }}` into a list string and then `json.parse` it the code works, although there's a problem with the reversed (lat, lon) since this area which is supposed to appear in the UK, now shows somewhere in the Indian Ocean near Kenya:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function map_init(map, options) {
        // parse geojson
        var polygon_str = "{{ obj.geometry.coords }}";
        polygon_str = polygon_str.replace(/\(/g, '[').replace(/\)/g, ']')
        var polygon = JSON.parse(polygon_str);

        // zoom to point
        //map.setView([51.9923, -2.1580], 12);
        map.setView([-2.1580, 51.9923], 12);

        // get polygon
        L.polygon(polygon).addTo(map);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you log that object to the console, `console.log("{{ obj.geometry.geojson }}"`

Is it an actual geojson object?

Comment: No it's apparently a `string`, the error might be caused by that. I've tried `JSON.parse()` but got this error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data`. I don't think there's a problem with the formatting of the geojson returned, because it displays well on the Leaflet map on the Django backend.

Comment: Note that Leaflet uses Lon, Lat as the order, and so your object you've got there looks like it's in the wrong order. (Most things do use Lon, Lat order, as it fits the X, Y order.)

Comment: When I open with a text editor the `GeoJSON` file, I've transferred to the `PostgreSQL` database table (with `ogr2ogr`), I see that the order is correct ([ -2.185909173008958, 52.013298980833333 ]). I'm not sure though about leaflet using the (lon, lat) order, because when I've added a marker point the order had to be (lat, lon) instead.

Comment: Hey @hakim, looking at the docs, it seem markers and such need lat, lon for leaflet, but GeoJSON should be lon, lat.

Comment: @AlexLeith, yeah apparently that's right ([link](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#polygon-l-polygon)). There has to be a more elegant solution to this problem though, than to go through the polygon point by point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using `Mapbox` instead of `Leaflet` since the former uses the same order `lonlat` as `GeoJSON`.

On the Django-side, the object passed as a GeoJSON from the view to the template wasn't escaped, to avoid having all the quotes (") replaced with a '& amp ;' (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051375)):

**View:**

```py
return render(request, 'maps/detail.html', {
    'obj_json': obj.geometry.geojson
})
```

**Template:**

```js
<script>
    // parse geojson string
    var obj_json = '{{ obj_json | safe }}';
    var polygon = JSON.parse(obj_json);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try it without the quotes, so:

```
var polygon = {{ obj.geometry.geojson }};
```

You may need to transform it first, like:

```
var polygon = {{ obj.geom.transform(4326).geojson }};
```

(From [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2191/3399).)

Comment: Thanks Alex, but `obj.geometry.srid` already returns `4326` without any transformation. I don't think the problem is on `Django`'s side, as the error returned is a Javascript error (`Leaflet`-related). I would say it's because the js variable `polygon` is a string not an array, though it would be weird that no straightforward way is available to fix it.